# How to load an HTML page inside the content section of another HTML page using jQuery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am a newbie to jQuery Mobile, I have created an HTML page in which I have created a panel with contents in a listview. On clicking each list item ,It should redirect to another HTML page , which should be loaded inside the content part of the same HTML page containing panel.Anybody have any suggestions guidelines? I need a little help here..

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#panelid').load('/item-selected.html');
```

Where `panelid` it's the id attribute of your results panel and `item-selected.html` is the detail page of your item.

Comment: It's not working , I have tried <iframe> and it got worked !!! anyways thanks buddy :)